# Not able to display data through ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

i want to show the restaurant after selecting its area from dropdown list. but my code did not show the restaurant name and the menu button of that restaurant please tell me where i did mistake

Its my model code

```
function select_record($table, $where = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select();
    if ($where) $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //  echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller code

```
public function get_rests()

{
    $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
    $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
    $where = array(
        'city_id' => $cit_id,
        'city_area_id' => $area
    );
    $data = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant', $where);
    $html = '<div class="container" id="">
                        <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%" id="">
                            <thread>
                                <tr style="width: 56%;">
                                    <th> No. </th>
                                    <th style=""> Restaurant Names </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thread>
                            <tbody>
                            <th> <span value="'. $data[0]->restaurant_id . '" class="res_id"></span></th>
                                <th style=""> </th>
                                <th style=""> <span value="'. $data[0]->restaurant_name . '" class="res_id"></span> </th>
                                <th style="width: 1%" > <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a> </th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>';
    echo json_encode(array(
        'data' => $html
    ));

}
```

Script code

```
function get_rests() {

    var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
    var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
        data: {
            cit_id: city_id,
            areaID: area_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            $('#restaurant').html(response.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Its view code

```
<div id="restaurant">


</div>
```

when  i did  alert(response.data);

```
     <div class="container" id="">
        <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%" id="">

            <thread>
                <tr style="width: 56%;">

                    <th>

                        No.

                    </th>

                    <th style="">

                        Restaurant Names

                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>


<th>

                <span value="1" class="res_id"></span></th>
                    <th style="">
                    </th>

                    <th style="">

                                 <span value="salten paper" class="res_id"></span>

                    </th>

                    <th style="width: 1%" >
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id;?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a>

                    </th>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
```

Please tell me where i did mistake

Comment: `alert(response.data)` and paste what its alerting..

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting the `response` from ajax properly. `$('#restaurant').html(response.data);` should be:

```
$('#restaurant').html(response);
```

Also change

```
url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
```

to

```
url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/bulk_controller/get_rests",
```

Comment: I applied all your saggession but  in response same output is displayed

Comment: change your controller echo to `echo $html;` @falakhamid

Comment: please tell me what changes i made in controller echo

Comment: change `echo json_encode(array('data' => $html));` to `echo $html;` @falakhamid

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

You should return it rather than `echo`, Also you have to set the request header as **json**

Model:

```
function select_record($table, $where = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);// this should come right after select statement
    if ($where) $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //  echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function get_rests()

{
    $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
    $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
    $where = array(
        'city_id' => $cit_id,
        'city_area_id' => $area
    );
    $data = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant', $where);
    $html = '<div class="container" id="">
                        <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%" id="">
                            <thread>
                                <tr style="width: 56%;">
                                    <th> No. </th>
                                    <th style=""> Restaurant Names </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thread>
                            <tbody>
                            <th> <span value="'. $data[0]->restaurant_id . '" class="res_id"></span></th>
                                <th style=""> </th>
                                <th style=""> <span value="'. $data[0]->restaurant_name . '" class="res_id"></span> </th>
                                <th style="width: 1%" > <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a> </th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>';
    return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array(
                'data' => $html,
            )));

}
```

Script:

```
function get_rests() {

    var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
    var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
        data: {
            'cit_id': city_id,
            'areaID': area_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response)
            $('#restaurant').html(response.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @jloker please tell me how to set the request header  as json

Comment: @falakhamid check my code above..And replace yours with mine